# QR Scanner in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, qr-code, drawerlayout

I'm creating an app that requires to Scan QR codes, I'm also using the drawer layout created like this : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html .So the scanner should be inside a fragment, I've been looking and trying to modify the examples where they implement that into an activity but I can't get it to work. I would like to use ZXingScannerView.

could anyone help me?

Comment: I didn't get the what do u need is it the fragment code? if so https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zbar-sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zbar/sample/FullScannerFragment.java

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?  I'm doing the exact same thing and can't find a good tutorial on using the ZXingScannerView in a fragment.